# PHP version and PHP Notice: Undefined variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to clone a site that's currently live on my local server and I'm getting some PHP Notice on my localhost error log.
I understand why that warnings but what I cannot understand is why it's working on the server so I guess it's related with the PHP version.
Thise are the exact warning:

**PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: value**
**PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: url**

And this is the code:

```
<?
$catdata=$catobj->getallCategory();
$temp=1;    
foreach($catdata as $value){
    $search = array(' ','!','?','"','(',')',' ','&',',','/');
    $replace = array('-',' ',' ',' ','','','-','-','','-');                 
    $sub_title=str_replace($search, $replace, strtolower(trim($value['cat_title'])));
    $url="jobs-in-".str_replace(' ','-',stripslashes($sub_title));
?>
<? if(count($catdata)==$temp){?>
    <li  style="background:none; padding-right:0"><a href="<?=$this->baseUrl()?>/<?=$url?>"><?=ucwords(stripslashes($value[cat_title]))?></a></li>
<? }else{?>
    <li><a href="<?=$this->baseUrl()?>/<?=$url?>"><?=ucwords(stripslashes($value[cat_title]))?></a></li>
```

Comment: `error_reporting` and `display_errors` are different.

Comment: Sorry, the warning is for value not val. The short open tags are enabled